# Voltage divider, how do I calculate Vout?

Tags: voltage-divider

I try my best to translate it.

[image]

\$Z_2 = 20\Omega\$, and \$Z_1\$ is resistance variable which ranges from \$10\Omega\$ to \$200\Omega\$

I need to calculate \$V_{out}\$ for the value \$Z_1 = 15\Omega\$ and again for \$160\Omega\$.

This is some information  I've tried

$$V_{out} = V_{in} \times \frac{I\times Z_2}{I\times(Z_1 + Z_2)}$$

Therefore

$$V_{out} = V_{in} \times \frac{Z_2}{Z_1 + Z_2}$$

Now I can get the \$V_{in}\$ (*from a book*) using the equation:

$$V_{in} = I (Z_1 + Z_2)$$

But if I combine \$V_{in}\$ into the equation, I get:

$$V_{out} = V_{in} \times \frac{Z_2}{Z_1 + Z_2}$$

$$V_{out} = I\times(Z_1 + Z_2) \times \frac{Z_2}{Z_1 + Z_2}$$

Which is missing information for the \$I\$?

Is there another way I could calculate the \$V_{out}\$? or this question is just formed incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't even need to think about current.

$$V_{out} = V_{in} \times \frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}$$

If you don't know \$V_{in}\$, you can't specify a value, only the output voltage in terms of \$V_{in}\$.

Comment: Thanks (and sorry I'm a binary engineer don't understand this very much), and yes this is what I'm affraid for, it's written wrongly, thank you!

Comment: @Bravo Notice how in the last line of your calculations, it basically just simplifies down to \$V_{out}=IZ_2\$ which while true, doesn't actually help you. In fact it's going the other way that gets us to the equation in my answer (and the second one in your question).

Comment: Ya, I got that too, which why I somehow refer to the *I*, this was written by an assistant of professor, but perhaps he just want some folks here to represent it as a plain *`Vin`*. Anyway thank you again!

Comment: @Bravo if a question is unclear or you have doubts, the simplest thing to do is go back to your professor who set the questions and ask for clarification.

Comment: I've just noticed that maybe he wanted to show us that no matter how much the value of *R1* (15 or 160) ohm , the *`Vout`* will be *same* , since     it's *I X Z2 (=  I x 20 ohm)*, Thank you again Tom Carpenter!

Comment: @Bravo, I hope that's not the lesson you took away, because changing R1 will change I, and that will change Vout.